# how to do two operations from a single click of a button in android

Tags: java, android, onclick

hi i have created an app. I already have a coding to find the latitude and longitude of a place. But in that coding i have button and when the button is clicked the values get displayed

In my app i have a button named start, when i click the button it moves over to a new page. 
In that page i have placed two layouts. In one layout i have placed some textview and edit text data with a ok button. In the other layout i have placed the coding of latitude  and longitude.

Now when i click the start button the new page must get opened and at the same  time the current latitude and longitude must get displayed.

pls give help me in performing both the operations in the same page.......

Comment: where you have to display that value ?

Comment: code? sounds like an Async for lat-long would be good.

Comment: Please edit your original question to include the new information instead of posting it again. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the down vote... You should edit you other question and not ask the same question again. Or at least reference the other question so people understand it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need AsyncTask. You just have to update your views with information you obtain in `loadCoords();`.

Try something like:

```
  Coords coords = loadCoords();
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
  setContentView(R.layout.add);
  t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t1);
  t1.setText(coords.getLatitude());
```

P.S. Just a point: Java Convention advices you to name methods in Camel Case, like this: loadCoords() - the first letter is always small.

Comment: do you say that i have to create a class named Coords and there  i should place my coding for the value??

Comment: Yes, create a class and put there the results of your measurements.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Toast` message to display the latitude and longitude, and then should open another activity.The `Toast` will remain visible for a particular time, and you'll also get your activity opened.